# My DELETE method is coming up as a 404 response

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, methods, mern

I am working on a MERN stack project and my delete method does not seem not functioning properly. I am getting a 404 response with the correct id of the object I am trying to delete.

```
<% if(user.cards.length) { %>
<h2>Here are your cards: </h2>
<% user.cards.forEach(c => { %>
<article>
  <h2><%= c.title %></h2>
  <a href="<%= c.link %>">Go to Source</a>
  <p><%= c.scripture %></p>
  <p>
    <%= c.description.substr(0, 50) + '...' %>
    <a href="/cards/<%= c._id %>">see more</a>
  </p>

  <form action="/cards/<%= c._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="DELETE">
  </form>
</article>
<% }) %>
```

Above is part of the ejs I am using.

```
// DELETE
cardsRouter.delete('/cards/:id', auth.isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    user.cards.pull(req.params.id);
    await user.save();
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Above is the route and methods to delete the card.

I should mention also that the cards are a part of a 'user' model, so they are attatched to whichever user is currently logged on.

I have tried to refactor the code many times, I had a problem with mongoDB where I had to refactor all of my routes because of an update that mongo had done. I am not sure this is what ended up affecting the delete method.